# Can't find request userID in array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Following a fairly simple tutorial on nodejs and expressjs to implement user permissions on routes. A small middle ware function to set the req.user just does not work for me and I keep getting undefined.

here is the middle ware function(and I do have the app set to use the middle ware):

```
function setUser(req, res, next) {
  const userID = req.body.userId;
  if (userID) {
    req.user = users.find((user) => user.id === userID);
    console.log(req.user);
  }
  next();
}
```

here is the user data I am using:

```
const ROLE = {
  ADMIN: 'admin',
  BASIC: 'basic',
};

module.exports = {
  ROLE: ROLE,
  users: [
    { id: 1, name: 'Kyle', role: ROLE.ADMIN },
    { id: 2, name: 'Sally', role: ROLE.BASIC },
    { id: 3, name: 'Joe', role: ROLE.BASIC },
  ],
  projects: [
    { id: 1, name: "Kyle's Project", userId: 1 },
    { id: 2, name: "Sally's Project", userId: 2 },
    { id: 3, name: "Joe's Project", userId: 3 },
  ],
};
```

am I not filtering the user data set correctly?? I do have it imported at the top of my file.

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title, and explain the specific problem you're having.

Comment: What does `console.log(typeof userID)` show? I'll bet it's a string, but `user.id` is a number.

Comment: Do we assume that `users` is imported as `const users = require('./users.js');` and the "user data" you are using is inside "users.js" (file name may be different). Between comparing different value types and how you import, there could be multiple issues.

Comment: I don't believe you can modify the user object in the request. `req.user = [anything]` is invalid, correct?

Comment: @Barmar You were correct, it returned a string, so using parseInt(req.body.userId) solved my problem. Thank you and I will be sure to improve my posts in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Can you show me your import line? What name did you assign the requireJS object to? It should probably be:

```
function setUser(req, res, next) {
  const userID = req.body.userId;
  if (userID) {
    req.user = importName.users.find((user) => user.id === userID);
    console.log(req.user);
  }
  next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the `userId` in the request is a string, so `user.id === userID` is false, try hardcoding the userId to 1 and confirm (i.e. `1 === user.id`)

Answer (score 0):

For me it seems like `req.body` is undefined, so js interpretator cannot find `userId` of empty, undefined object.

You can bugfix it like this:

```
function setUser(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body); // add this, does it provides anything?
  const userID = req.body.userId;
  if (userID) {
    req.user = users.find((user) => user.id === userID);
    console.log(req.user);
  }
  next();
}
```

it is worth notice, that expressjs from the box doesn't parse POST body - you should include proper middleware - [json one](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.json) or [url encoded one](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.urlencoded)

Comment: If `req.body` is undefined, `if (userID)` would be false and it wouldn't log anything. But they say they're getting `undefined`.

Comment: The question says **I do have the app set to use the middle ware**